# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui'

Tags: python, pythonista

I am trying to run the following script from the pythonista drawing app example in IDLE on my macbook, but am getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui'"

Website for the UI itself:  https://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/ui.html

I can't seem to find any install procedures for this ui and would appreciate any help, as it runs on my ipad so just want to see how it runs on my mac as well.

```
import ui
import photos
import console

# The PathView class is responsible for tracking
# touches and drawing the current stroke.
# It is used by SketchView.

class PathView (ui.View):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        self.flex = 'WH'
        self.path = None
        self.action = None
    
    def touch_began(self, touch):
        x, y = touch.location
        self.path = ui.Path()
        self.path.line_width = 8.0
        self.path.line_join_style = ui.LINE_JOIN_ROUND
        self.path.line_cap_style = ui.LINE_CAP_ROUND
        self.path.move_to(x, y)
    
    def touch_moved(self, touch):
        x, y = touch.location
        self.path.line_to(x, y)
        self.set_needs_display()
    
    def touch_ended(self, touch):
        # Send the current path to the SketchView:
        if callable(self.action):
            self.action(self)
        # Clear the view (the path has now been rendered
        # into the SketchView's image view):
        self.path = None
        self.set_needs_display()
    
    def draw(self):
        if self.path:
            self.path.stroke()

# The main SketchView contains a PathView for the current
# line and an ImageView for rendering completed strokes.
# It also manages the 'Clear' and 'Save' ButtonItems that
# are shown in the title bar.

class SketchView (ui.View):
    def __init__(self, width=1024, height=1024):
        self.bg_color = 'white'
        iv = ui.ImageView(frame=(0, 0, width, height))
        pv = PathView(frame=self.bounds)
        pv.action = self.path_action
        self.add_subview(iv)
        self.add_subview(pv)
        save_button = ui.ButtonItem()
        save_button.title = 'Save Image'
        save_button.action = self.save_action
        clear_button = ui.ButtonItem()
        clear_button.title = 'Clear'
        clear_button.tint_color = 'red'
        clear_button.action = self.clear_action
        self.right_button_items = [save_button, clear_button]
        self.image_view = iv
    
    def path_action(self, sender):
        path = sender.path
        old_img = self.image_view.image
        width, height = self.image_view.width, self.image_view.height
        with ui.ImageContext(width, height) as ctx:
            if old_img:
                old_img.draw()
            path.stroke()
            self.image_view.image = ctx.get_image()
    
    def clear_action(self, sender):
        self.image_view.image = None
    
    def save_action(self, sender):
        if self.image_view.image:
            # We draw a new image here, so that it has the current
            # orientation (the canvas is quadratic).
            with ui.ImageContext(self.width, self.height) as ctx:
                self.image_view.image.draw()
                img = ctx.get_image()
                photos.save_image(img)
                console.hud_alert('Saved')
        else:
            console.hud_alert('No Image', 'error')
    
# We use a square canvas, so that the same image
# can be used in portrait and landscape orientation.
w, h = ui.get_screen_size()
canvas_size = max(w, h)

sv = SketchView(canvas_size, canvas_size)
sv.name = 'Sketch'
sv.present('fullscreen')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say IDLE, which Pythonista does not have, so I am assuming that you are trying this outside Pythonista. ui module is a proprietary part of Pythonista, and not installable separately.

If you want to use UIKit classes with Python on a Mac, you either need a new M1 Macbook that can run the same Pythonista app that you run on your iPad, or you have to look at something like [Rubicon](https://rubicon-objc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to bridge from Python to the UIKit classes, essentially duplicating the Pythonista ui module functionality.

Comment: Ah yeah, I'm using the Pythonista IDE on my ipad and the IDLE IDE on my macbook, so figured I could just copy and paste between them, assuming all modules were installed on both, with a "pip3 install XXX" type of terminal command, but I think you are right that this is a proprietary module that Pythonista uses that is not available in to other python IDEs. I suppose another GUI framework would be the next option, Rubicon looks interesting but I am currently learning Python and Swift alongside one another (so far they are not too different) but not sure I can handle learning objectiveC too haha